# transform: rotate does nothing on a span

Tags: css

I have a dummy span:

```
<span></span>
```

I want it rotated on hover:

```
@font-face { font-family: "ionicons"; src: url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1"); src: url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.1") format("truetype"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.1") format("woff"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.svg?v=2.0.1#Ionicons") format("svg"); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; }

span {
  display: block;
}

span:after {
  content: '\f125';
  font-family: 'ionicons';
}

span:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

However nothing seems to happen. Why is that?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kfzLbse7/1/)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "ionicons";
  src: url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1");
  src: url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.eot?v=2.0.1#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.1") format("truetype"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.woff?v=2.0.1") format("woff"), url("https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/fonts/ionicons.svg?v=2.0.1#Ionicons") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

span {
  display: block;
}

span:after {
  content: '\f125';
  font-family: 'ionicons';
}

span:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

How do I rotate the span around its center point?

Comment: Try with -90deg and you'll understand, to fix it make it inline or lower it's width

Comment: You need a transition CSS rule to see the animation.  Added BG color to this fiddle so you can see the animation (glyph goes off-screen w/ animation): https://jsfiddle.net/6kv8L7qd/

Comment: I see. Well, how do I rotate the span around its center point?

Comment: transform-origin: center center; (https://jsfiddle.net/6kv8L7qd/1/)  Google works too ;)

Comment: To rotate around the center point, use `transform-origin: center;`
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: I don’t think this is a dup of that particular question since the `<span>` is set to `display: block` in the example.

Comment: use `inline-block` and not block

Comment: @TedWhitehead center is the default value and it's the issue here because the center of a block element is the center of the screen since it's by default 100% width